# Allow all active user to login to django admin site

Tags: python, django, authentication, middleware

I am trying to allow all active user to login to admin site because as a default just staff and superusers are able to login to admin site.

I've tried to overwrite `clean` method in my custom crate/change forms but it didn't help

````
class User(GuardianUserMixin, AbstractUser):

    name = models.CharField(_("Name of User"), blank=True, max_length=255)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("users:detail", kwargs={"username": self.username})

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(GuardedModelAdminMixin, auth_admin.UserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    fieldsets = FIELDSETS
    list_display = ["username", "name", "is_active", "is_superuser", "is_staff"]
    search_fields = ["name", "username"]

class UserChangeForm(forms.UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(forms.UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = User


class UserCreationForm(forms.UserCreationForm):

    error_message = forms.UserCreationForm.error_messages.update(
        {"duplicate_username": _("This username has already been taken.")}
    )

    class Meta(forms.UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]

        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username

        raise 
    ValidationError(self.error_messages["duplicate_username"])```
````

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things that determine whether a user can access the Django Admin:

1. `User.is_staff`[1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff) must be set to `True`
2. The user will need the appropriate permissions for each model

There are multiple ways to set `is_staff` to `True` for all new users. The easiest would probably be to redefine `is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)` on your `User` model.

If you are not going to use per-model permissions you can also redefine `is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=True)` which will give the user all permissions on every model.

Note though that the Django Admin is primarily designed to be used by your developers and site administrators who know what they are doing, and not most regular users.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I will create other models based on that user model, so I need to keep is_active and is_staff separate. Now I am not able to go around the `AdminAuthenticationForm` which always checks if the `is_staff` is True.